# mkdir() not working with this code for creating random directory name for upload photo

Tags: php, html, mysql, mkdir

```
// profile picture upload
if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
    if ( ((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
            || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png")
            || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))
        && (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576) ) //1 Megabyte
    {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);

        mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");
```

This is the directory all my files are: `C:/xampp/htdocs/asweb`

And this is where I want to keep the new directory: `C:/xampp/htdocs/asweb/userdata/profile_pics`

Comment: test it with <?php mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/new");

Comment: If you are creating multiple levels og folders, you have to set recursive to true as Drew suggested. (Recursive is the third argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the following:

```
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
echo $rand_dir_name.$b;    // ojTxNHb0RuiyKze

mkdir("c:\\dev\\".$rand_dir_name,0777,TRUE);
```

It made `c:\dev\ojTxNHb0RuiyKze` no problem. I went in there and saved a text file.

The Manual [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) says

**mode**

> The mode is 0777 by default, which means the widest possible
>   access. For more information on modes, read the details on the chmod()
>   page.
>
> Note: mode is **ignored** on Windows. Note that you probably want to
>   specify the mode as an octal number, which means it should have a
>   leading zero. The mode is also modified by the current umask, which
>   you can change using umask().

However on linux, have it follow chmod values.

### Edit: op can't do it, here we go again:

```
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
echo $rand_dir_name.$b;    // l1TGXW3kgQcr2N5
mkdir("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\asweb\\userdata\\profile_pics\\".$rand_dir_name,0777,TRUE);
```

made `C:\xampp\htdocs\asweb\userdata\profile_pics\l1TGXW3kgQcr2N5` no problem

Comment: tell me what stub directory to create the dir off of, I will make that stub dir first. The **FULL** directory path.

Comment: your slashes going the wrong way, you did not double slashes throughout, you did not end the stub dir with a slash. Pay attention to details

Comment: trust me hav used the other slash its not still working hav also ended d sud dir with a slash too .......its not still responding .. as i load the page on my browser i click upload photo then i click the photo the i click am upload button then i go and check but it still doestt workkkkk hav been trying sinceeee last week i still dunno where the mistake is

Comment: create a  php file that contains this: `mkdir("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\asweb\\userdata\\profile_pics\\NEWDIR",0777,TRUE);   `  ... and what do you get

Comment: i juust wrote that code on new page and it worked its like they is/are some certain codes thats stoping the code from working on my account settings page

Comment: it is because that is perfect, the  c:\\dev\\  was perfect, the C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\asweb\\userdata\\profile_pics\\ is perfect, but your other code is not.

Comment: after pasting all my codes to a new page i discovered the problem was this but dunno know y can any one explain        :<div id="aswrap">
<form action="account_settings.php" method="POST">
<h2>EDIT YOUR ACCOUNT SETTINGS</h2><br/><br/><br/>
<hr/>
<br/>